# EF Core: Strategies for segmenting IQueryable for re-use & loading selected properties only

Tags: entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I'm looking for a way efficiently generate and re-use part of a (fairly large) query in Entity Framework Core.

My goals are as follows:

1. Generate efficient SQL; including returning only the columns
   needed from the relevant child tables, and avoiding N+1 scenarios
2. Abstract and separate the part of the queryable that runs from the grand-child level and below (first level of ThenInclude()), because this portion of the query will be used on other parent-level entities which have common grand-child entities, and I want to keep the code DRY.

My current query looks something like this (simplified) example:

```
var itemDetailsQuery = getQueryable(x => x.Id == itemId);
var item = await itemDetailsQuery.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

private IQueryable<Item> getQueryable(Expression<Func<Item,bool>> predicate)

    {
        return _itemRepository
        .GetAll()
        .Where(predicate)
        .Include(x => x.ItemChildren)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.ItemGrandChildren)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.ItemGreatGrandChildren1)

        .Include(x => x.ItemChildren)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.ItemGrandChildren)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.ItemGreatGrandChildren2)

        .Include(x => x.ItemChildren)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.ItemGrandChildren)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.ItemGreatGrandChildren3)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.ItemGreatGreatGrandChildren)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.ItemGreatGreatGreatGrandChildren);
    }
```

The above works, but:

1. loads every column from the relevant rows / entities and is therefore inefficient
2. I have to duplicate the query code if I want to load entities of type ItemGrandChildren and below from a parent entity type other than Item.

I found the post below which was very intriguing, suggesting usage of expressions and projections to achieve the kind of result I wanted, which was very neat because I could leverage an expression as a projection in each class:

https://benjii.me/2018/01/expression-projection-magic-entity-framework-core/

My implementation of this was as follows, with each child class having its own projection, so multiple levels are chained together using this strategy (note the ToList() is necesary because my collection properties are ICollections as opposed to IEnumerables; although I am worried this may cause premature execution:

```
private IQueryable<Item> getQueryable(Expression<Func<Item,bool>> predicate)
{
    return _itemRepository
    .GetAll()
    .AsExpandable()
    .Where(predicate)
    .Select(x => new Item
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        ItemChildren = x.ItemChildren.AsQueryable().Select(ItemChild.Projection).ToList(),
    });
}
```

However, when I try this, past the second layer of children, nothing is loaded; it may be that this was not designed to be used in a chained manner with multiple layers of nesting.

I've investigated alternative strategies, including extension methods, but although I can get these to work replacing first-tier Includes, I cannot find a way to have these replace a ThenInclude so I could do something like:

```
    private IQueryable<Item> getQueryable(Expression<Func<Item,bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _itemRepository
        .GetAll()
        .Where(predicate)
        .Include(x => x.ItemChildren)
            .IncludeGrandChildren();
    }

    private IIncludableQueryable<ItemGrandChildren, ItemGreatGrandChildren3> IncludeGrandChildren(this IQueryable<ItemGrandChildren> values)
    {
        return values
            .Include(x => x.ItemGreatGrandChildren1)
            .Include(x => x.ItemGreatGrandChildren2)
            .Include(x => x.ItemGreatGrandChildren3)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.ItemGreatGreatGrandChildren)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.ItemGreatGreatGreatGrandChildren);
    }
```

I get the feeling that I'm missing or misunderstanding something fundamental, but any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: [NeinLinq.EntityFrameworkCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#neinlinqentityframeworkcore), [LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#linqkitmicrosoftentityframeworkcore), AutoMapper [Queryable Extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) etc. - all these address the same issue to some sort of degree.

Comment: @IvanStoev, thanks for the hints. I had briefly looked at the AutoMapper Queryable Extensions and discounted this as I wanted a little more control over the process, although the .ProjectTo<T>() syntax is very appealing. I will investigate NeinLinq and LinqKit further.